# What could diminish MySqls performance?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Basically we are very happy with Mysqls performance, similar queries are completed in a split second. Now we face a problem with this query

```
SELECT dc.id,dmr.art_id 
FROM dmr 
JOIN dma ON dma.id = dmr.dml_id
JOIN dc  ON  dc.id = dma.dc_id
WHERE  dmr.art_id = 2285
```

It takes 50 seconds to fetch 5021 rows. A missing index is probably the most common cause for issues like that. So I preceded the query by EXPLAIN and got this query plan which shows that only indexes are used no sequential scans.

The tables dmr and dma have 3 million rows each, dc has 6000 rows.

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                 | key            | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dmr   | ref    | FKC33D5199F17E1825,ix_art_ref | ix_art_ref     | 5       | const              | 5021 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dma   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK8C6E1445153BBDC9    | PRIMARY        | 8       | dev.dmr.dml_id     |    1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dc    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY        | 8       | dev.dma.dc_id      |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
```

What could cause this problems?

MySql Version is 5.5 using InnoDB as engine. (Only default parameters on windows).

EDIT

When I remove the where clause, mysql returns the (huge) result set immediately.
The query plan in this case looks like:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys              | key                | key_len | ref        | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dc    | index | PRIMARY                    | FKAEB144C64FA71464 | 9       | NULL       | 4037 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dma   | ref   | PRIMARY,FK8C6E1445153BBDC9 | FK8C6E1445153BBDC9 | 9       | dev.dc.id  |  263 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dmr   | ref   | FKC33D5199F17E1825         | FKC33D5199F17E1825 | 9       | dev.dma.id |    1 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: You're most likely I/O bound by the hard disk. Increase `innodb_buffer_pool` size variable to 70% of your RAM. That way portion of working dataset will be kept in memory and lookup will be much faster.

Comment: try analyze table...http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: @Neville - I already did, it says status is ok.

Comment: Both query are using different execution plan.So, hint the mysql to use the index dc.FKAEB144C64FA71464

Comment: @ajreal thanks, but dc's primary key shouldn't be the starting point of the query (1st), we want to reduce the number of rows by starting with ix_art_ref which should reduce from 3M to 5k rows for the subsequent operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling mysql 5.5.17 and decided not to use the setting 'Developer Machine', I used the default settings for 'Server Machine'.
After that the query is performed in a few seconds (1st time) subsequent query perform
much better.

I suppose that in developer mode mysql is configured to save ram and doesn't buffer enough index pages for large tables.

The (re-)configuration can by accomplished with `MYSQL_HOME/bin/MySQLInstanceConfig`

[image]

A comparision of the old and new config files shows that these values were changed during the configuration:

```
tmp_table_size=103M old 18M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=205M old 35M
key_buffer_size=175M old 25M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=7M old 3499K
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M old 1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=339M old 47M
```

Comment: As suggested in a comment, your `innodb_buffer_pool` got increased. You can do that manually by editing my.cnf file or reconfigure the instance trough that GUI. Either way, your working dataset resides in memory now. In other words - it still might be slow from time to time.

Comment: @N.B. Sorry my bad, I didn't understood what you meant by 'working dataset'. Now everything is clear if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks for you help.

Comment: It's all ok, I'm not "hunting" for rep, your answer and the comments will make things clear for the next guy with the same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the tables are very fragmented and MySQL has to go all over the disk to fetch those 5021 rows?